# Ektron: synchronization between two servers stopped

Tags: ektron

We have problem with Ektron synchronization between two servers.

It stopped couple days ago. We tried the “Pause/Resume” button, but that didn’t work.

Do you know where to look for errors and how to troubleshoot this problem?

Please advise.

Updates :

version Ektron 8.6.1

synchronization schedule : daily at 11PM

Restarted services on both machines.

Found error in C:\Program Files (x86)\Ektron\EktronWindowsService40\log\errors

Type : System.InvalidOperationException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
Message : The security identifier is not allowed to be the owner of this object.
Source : mscorlib
Help link :
Data : System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
TargetSite : Void Persist(System.String, System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle, System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlSections, System.Object)
HResult : -2146233079
Stack Trace : at System.Security.AccessControl.NativeObjectSecurity.Persist(String name, SafeHandle handle, AccessControlSections includeSections, Object exceptionContext)
at System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemSecurity.Persist(String fullPath)
at Ektron.FileSync.Common.FileSyncUtils.ChangePermissions(String filePath, String dirPath)

Stack Trace : at System.Security.AccessControl.NativeObjectSecurity.Persist(String name, SafeHandle handle, AccessControlSections includeSections, Object exceptionContext)
at System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemSecurity.Persist(String fullPath)
at Ektron.FileSync.Common.FileSyncUtils.ChangePermissions(String filePath, String dirPath)

Severity: Error
Title:EktronWindowsServices Exception

Application Domain: Ektron.ASM.EktronServices40.exe
Process Id: 1568
Process Name: E:\Program Files (x86)\Ektron\EktronWindowsService40\Ektron.ASM.EktronServices40.exe

Comment: Have you looked at the knowledge base? http://world.episerver.com/kb/search

Comment: Something you can try is restarting the Ektron Windows Service on both the sending and receiving machines to kill the process entirely and start it over. Note that you should restart the service on BOTH.

Comment: Also would be great to include version information.

Comment: FYI - pause / resume refers to the sync schedule. Example, if you have an hourly sync schedule configured, the pause will prevent the future occurrences until resumed. It doesn't pause an in-progress sync.

Comment: I see you've edited your post - did any of the above help? Any specific errors? Screenshot of what's going on?

Comment: I've found error into log file (added to post). and restarted service on both machines. sync set for once a day so I will check tomorrow if it helped.

Comment: Restarting Ektron.ASM.EktronServices40.exe services on both computer  helped  !Thank you !!!